# O(1) code to count multiples of a number in a range?

Tags: c, math, integer, 32-bit, division

How do I do this in constant time (I do not want to brute for iterate from a to b)?

```
// return number of multiples of c in [a,b]
long count_multiples(int a, int b, int c) {
   assert(b >= a && c != 0);
   // todo
   return -1;
}
```

This question looks deceptively simple but is harder than it looks because it has some corner cases e.g. must handle all cases (`a`,`b` can be negative/zero and `c` can be negative too and `a` may equal `b` may equal `c`). The result may not fit in 32-bit for one case (`a = 2^31`, `b = 2^31-1`, `c = 1 or -1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long count_multiples(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (b < a) return 0;
    if (c < 0) c = -c;
    long al = a, bl = b, cl = c;
    if (c == 1) return bl - al + 1;
    return ((bl + (b < 0 ? 1 : 0)) / cl) -
           ((al - (a > 0 ? 1 : 0)) / cl) +
           ((a <= 0 && b >= 0) ? 1 : 0);
}
```